# Display list/or table with Ruby on Rails from search result

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Ruby on Rails. I want to update the new.html.erb view to display search_result from album_controller.rb, after the search parameter is submitted. Can I create a hidden element and later display it through from the controller? search_results is an array of string arrays.

My goal to display a list of possible albums to choose from (obtained from the http get request), and then let the user choose which search result to carry on with.

**new.html.erb**

```
<h4>Search for Album</h4>

<%= form_with(url: "/albums/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for: ") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

**album_controller.rb**

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    puts "the new method was just called"
  end

  def search
    puts "inside search method"
    @search_param = params[:q]
    puts @search_param

    if params[:q] # if not null
      #perform artist and album search
      search_result = http_request(@search_param)
    end
  end

  def http_request(search_input)
    # search for album
    website = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?"
    search_album = "method=album.search&album=" + search_input + "&"
    api_key = "api_key=&"
    format = "format=json&"
    limit = "limit=15"

    url = website + search_album + api_key + format + limit

    response = HTTParty.get(url)
    pretty_json = JSON.pretty_generate(response.parsed_response)
    obj = JSON.parse(pretty_json)

    returnArray = []
    for result in obj["results"]["albummatches"]["album"]
      tempArray = [result["name"], result["artist"], result["image"][3]["#text"]]
      returnArray.append(tempArray)
    end

    return returnArray
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  post "albums/new" #to later post to album db

  get "albums/search"  #search route in new.html.erb

  resources :albums

  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

Comment: If you want to submit a search inquery specific to say an album.  Why not something like: `Album.where(title: "inquery_data")`

Comment: The album obj is not created yet. I want to display a list of possible albums to choose from (obtained from the http get request), and then let the user choose which search result to carry on with.

Comment: I don't quite understand the flow here.  You want to give them a list of albums to choose from, and then search the stuff that that album choice causes?  Seems kind of overly complex.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific, first time posting. I want maintain a personal collection of albums in a database. The flow is like this: search for an album (through music api), http get request returns json, parse json into 15 search results, display search result to user (where I'm having problems right now), then finally have user choose which search result to add to database.

Comment: Having trouble putting that json into the view then?

Comment: Essentially yes. I want to access the information obtained in the controller from the view.

Comment: To use a variable in the view, it has to be an instance variable(@var).  Depending on what the JSON looks like, you could create a new array in your controller that formats the json request, and do something like @new_array.each in the view.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails you want to build skinny controllers that contain the minimum of code and the only public methods should be the actions that correspond to your routes. This is because controllers are notoriously hard to test and bloat becomes a problem real fast.

HTTP calls, batch processing and other such tasks do not belong in your controller. Especially not if they touch the application boundary. Instead you want to create a client object that handles the HTTP call and models that encapsulate the data and normalize it for your application.

So lets start with the HTTP call:

```
# app/clients/audio_scobbler_client.rb
class AudioScrobblerClient
  include Httparty
  format :json
  base_uri "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/"

  def initialize(api_key:)
    @base_opts = {
      api_key: api_key,
      format: "json" # may be redundant
    }
  end

  def album_search(query, limit: 15)
    self.class.get(
      @base_opts.reverse_merge(
        method: 'album.search',
        limit: limit
      )
    )
  end
end
```

This gives you an object you can test separately from your controller and removes the mess of constructing query strings with string concatenation (never do this). It returns the JSON from performing the HTTP request and nothing more.

Then create a model that represents the search results in your application. Remember that persistence is not the only role of models in MVC.

```
# app/models/album.rb
class Album
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attr :artist, String
  attr :name, String
  attr :image, String
end
```

Now lets throw one more object into the the mix - a service object that does the API call and normalizes the values:

```
# app/services/audio_scrobbler_search.rb
class AudioScrobblerSearch
  def perform(query, **options)
    api_key = ENV["AUDIOSCROBBER_API_KEY"] # or use the encrypted secrets.
    json = AudioScrobblerClient.new(api_key: api_key).album_search(query, options)
    json.dig("results", "albummatches", "album").map do |result|
      # I have no idea what api response looks 
      # like but I have no doubt that you can figure this part out
      Album.new(
         artist: result["name"],
         name: result["name"],
         image: result["image"]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Then lets get rid of all the bloat in the controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  # you don't really need the new action at all since a search form can just loop back on itself
  # GET /albums/search?q=believe
  def search
    @search_query = params[:q]
    if @search_query
      @albums = AudioScrobblerSearch.perform(query)
    end
  end
end
```

And list the albums in the view:

```
<h4>Search for Album</h4>

<%= form_with(url: "/albums/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= f.label(:q, "Search for: ") %>
  <%= f.text_field(:q, value: @search_query) %>
  <%= f.submit("Search") %>
<% end %>

<% if @albums %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= tag.img src: album.image, alt: "Cover art for #{album.name}" %></td>
          <td><%= album.artist %></td>
          <td><%= album.name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% elsif @search_query.present? %>
  <p>No results to display :(</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please note that this answer is only meant to outline the general approach and I have not actually tested the api call at all. Some assembly will be required on your part and it most likely contains multiple errors.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I'm going through it now. I have a question. In audio_scrobbler_client, what is the purpose of "self.get". I get a NoMethodError at this point.

Comment: Also in the view, I see you iterate through @albums. But I'm unsure how a list of albums is created. In audio_scrobbler_search.rb, does Album.new() create a new album object AND append it to a list?

Comment: No -`Album.new(...)` just creates an instance of Album. Look at the line above it  `json.dig("results", "albummatches", "album")` gets the key `obj["results"]["albummatches"]["album"]`. [`.map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) iterates across the array and returns a new array with the value returned by the block. `for` loops are not used by anybody except beginners in ruby.

Comment: Sorry it should have been `self.class.get` which calls `HTTParty.get`.